# ASPX call WebMethod in page code behind from client jQuery - The real deal

Tags: jquery, asp.net, webforms, webmethod

Yes, I've read a lot, lot lot of posts which are all a little oriented on a particular detail or another thin difference than the main question that should be "How to call a code behind Method in ASPX on .NET 4.5 and over with parameters and returns values", simply basic tutorial.

I'm blasting my head off on my VS 2017 and 2015.

Here is the code of a simple WebForm solution (YEAH I know, but I have to do it in WebForm and not my dear MVC)

I use the basic MasterPage given by Visual Studio on building WebForm Project.

Here is the Interesting part of the SiteMasterPage (Note that I use EnablePageMethod):

```
<body>
    <form runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true" EnablePartialRendering="true">
            [...]//Microsoft script declaration
        </asp:ScriptManager>

        <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
            [...]        
        </div>
        <div class="container body-content">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server">
            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
            <hr />
            <footer>
                <p>&copy; <%: DateTime.Now.Year %> - My ASP.NET Application</p>
            </footer>
        </div>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Now here is my Default.aspx:

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="FinalAjaxCallTest._Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
            <br />
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon">@</span>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Placecholder" id="inputTest01">
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
        <button id="btnTest01" type="button" class="btn btn-warning">Default.aspx/TestReturnResult</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">FAKE</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">FAKE</button>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div id="content">
        <p>Tee test values should be replaced here</p>
    </div>
    <script>
        $("#btnTest01").click(function (e) {

            console.log("click");

            var dataValue = { data01: "This is", data02: $("#inputTest01").val() };

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Default.aspx/TestReturnResult",
                data: dataValue,
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                dataType: 'json'
            })
                .done(function (html) {
                    console.log("ajaxdone");
                    $("#content").clear().append(html);
                });
        });
    </script>
</asp:Content>
```

And the Code Behind:

```
Imports System.Web.Services

Public Class _Default
    Inherits Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    End Sub

    <WebMethod()>
    Public Shared Function TestReturnResult(data01 As String, data02 As String) As String

        Return $"<span class='badges'>{data01} is great with {data02}</span>"

    End Function

End Class
```

In earlier tests I had `error 500`  server code when I was Under .NET 4.5.2, now I got

> Status code: 401 / Unauthorized

Any help would be very appreciated, I don't want the wall I knock my head on to win!

Comment: Also, seems like you're returning a string on your endpoint and expecting JSON on the ajax call.

Comment: Are you sure you're POSTing to the right location? Watch the network traffic in the browser's debug tools. Also, use Postman or a similar tool to see if you can directly hit the web method.

Comment: @Kosch Json encoding shoudn't be handled automatically by JQuery ?

Comment: @mason Yeah I did obviously, and there U get 500 or 401 error

Comment: 500 or 401? Which is it?

Comment: Here is the full error : 
   Asked URL: http://localhost:53717/Default.aspx/TestReturnResult
   Transfer mMethod: POST
   Status Code: 401 / Unauthorized

Comment: I tried this also in the `AppStart/route.config` `settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Off``and now I get ann error 500.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I FINALLY found it myself.

2 very important things are :

1 - in route.config set  `settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Off`

2 - Use `Json.Stringify` to send your datas from ajax

My final ajax code :

```
 $("#btnTest01").click(function (e) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "<%= ResolveUrl("Default.aspx/TestReturnResult") %>",
                async: true,
                data: JSON.stringify({ data01: "Test01", data02: "Test02" }),
                contentType: 'application/json',
                dataType: 'json'
            })
                .done(function (result) {
                    $("#content").html(result.d);
                });
        });
```